# how to import jquery script from separate file

Tags: javascript, jquery, import, embed, var

i write me jquery script in html page like this:

```
<script> function pofileEditable(){
        var pFormEditable = $('#profi-form input');
        $('#pBtnSave').removeAttr('disabled', '');
        $('#pBtnEdit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#prof-form-anrede').removeAttr('disabled', '');
       
       } </script>
```

How can I write it in separate file ex like that `test.js`
and import it?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/test.js"></script>
```

I don't wont to use javascript method

```
var edit = document.getElementById("pBtnEdit");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just import jquery first and then import your own script:

```
<script src="jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>
<script src="my_jquery.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Best practice is to include your `js` file at the end of the HTML `body` tag, like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>


        <!-- your content here  -->




        <!-- If you want to use JQuery, load it before your js file here  -->
         <!-- your own js file  -->
        <script src = 'path/to-your-js-file/your-js-file.js'></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```